# webview across the platform. Architect View?

Tags: android, c++, ios, macos, qt

I have a c,linux background with less knowledge about web application. I came across some strange requirement, and finding difficult providing solution.

Requirement in Short:

One Code/multiple platforms[ mobile as well as desktop]

**What I know:**

**1) UI Front.**

Webview is provided across all mobile, desktop applications. 
     [ Atlease I know for: iOS, Mac, in Windows/Linux/Mac from QT ].

Conclusion: I can have html5 code, which can be utilized across desktop/mobile platform. 
  PROBLEM: How to do the native access from HTML/JavaScript.  We could go with the phonegap which
  supports Only mobile, but not desktop [ Correct me if I am wrong]. And if we go with QT, then
  not much support for android/iOS [ Correct me if I am wrong].

2) Writing Middle layer in c++:
    iOS/Windows/Mac/Android supports C++.

**Question:**

1. In iOS/Android I know how to bring the webview using Xcode. But how can I get the webview in Windows and Mac.
2. In Short, do we have any open source framework that supports Mac/Windows/iOS/Android
3. Is it possible to write our own Native function invoke mechanism from JavaScript to the C++ code, 
   which is common.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Honestly, just don't...this many platforms under one codebase is just going to cause more problems than it solves.  Your best bet is to separate out the non-UI parts and share THOSE.

Comment: @borrrden you mean connectivity between HTML/JavaScript to different Native SDKs?

Comment: For example, write the logic portion in a language that can be compiled to all the platforms, and then write the UI that displays it natively.  Android, Windows 8, and iOS are all so fundamentally different that it hurts...so I doubt you will ever get a satisfactory result from trying to write the UI with one set of code.

Comment: But HTML5 is same across right?. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.  :).

Comment: Sure, but good luck trying to make it responsive and able to use all the features of the platform.  Furthermore, the web view on Windows 8 is the biggest pain of all.

Comment: Furthermore, windows 8 WebView doesn't support HTML5

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :**

- You can launch the application by opening the browser or as plugin to browser,other wise for mobile webkit you need to have it ported on the platform u wish to run your app ie Mac,Windows ,etc
- U can easily partially port  code in multi-platform ,However u can find many opensource SDK like **phonegap , snehaTouch ,etc** to have application for all smart phone, **but not for mobile and desktop/laptop environment**, **multi-platform destop/laptop** you can go with Java application.
- Yes you can call native function in respective platform by invoking from webkit using javasript .,

So single code can either work in mobile OS , or counter part writing Java?c++ code will work in all Desktop/laptop OS